# Type error encountered: how to correct it?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, typeerror

I was trying to construct a matrix using Python 3.6.0 and in this program, while running it, I encountered a **type error** which stated that *'type' object is not subscriptable*.

```
#Matrix
x=int(input("Enter number of rows of      matrix: "))
y=int(input("Enter number of columns of matrix: "))
for i in range(x-1):
  for j in range(y-1):
    list[i][j]=int(input("Enter the    elements of the matrix row-wise: "))
print(list)
```

What does this message in the output mean?

What wrong did I do and how should I correct it?

Comment: please paste code snippet instead of picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call your variable "list". That's a reserved word.

You should instantiate a list like so

```
my_list = []
for i in range(0,3):
    my_list.append([])
    for j in range(0,3):
       my_list[i].append(int(input('enter cell value')))
```

That gives

```
enter cell value1
enter cell value1
enter cell value1
enter cell value1
enter cell value1
enter cell value1
enter cell value1
enter cell value1
enter cell value1
>>> my_list
    [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Why do i start with an empty list? And what does the error message i received mean?

Comment: The error says the object "list" which is not the one you want but Python's list object, is not an array (you can't sub-script it). Also you can't just do some_list[1][3] if Python doesn't know that some_list is actually a list